IndexOutOfBoundsException when deleting items in Kotlin Multiplatform Compose app
I'm building a Kotlin Multiplatform application using Jetpack Compose. The app includes a list of todo items with the ability to add and remove items. However, I'm encountering an IndexOutOfBoundsException when I try to delete an item from the list.
Here are the relevant parts of my code:
TodoViewModel.kt
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow

class TodoViewModel {
    private val _todoList = MutableStateFlow<List<Todo>>(emptyList())
    val todos: StateFlow<List<Todo>> get() = _todoList

    init {
        loadTodos()
    }

    private fun loadTodos() {
        _todoList.value = TodoManager.getTodos()
    }

    fun addTodo(title: String) {
        TodoManager.addTodo(title)
        loadTodos()
    }

    fun removeTodo(id: Int) {
        TodoManager.removeTodo(id)
        loadTodos()
    }
}

TodoManager.kt
import java.time.Instant
import java.util.*

object TodoManager {
    private var todoList = mutableListOf<Todo>()

    fun addTodo(title: String) {
        todoList.add(Todo(System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), title, Date.from(Instant.now())))
    }

    fun removeTodo(id: Int) {
        todoList.removeIf { it.id == id }
    }

    fun getTodos(): List<Todo> {
        return todoList
    }
}

Todo.kt
import java.util.Date

data class Todo(
    var id: Int,
    var title: String,
    var createdAt: Date
)

MainUI
@Composable
fun TodoListPage(todoViewModel: TodoViewModel = TodoViewModel()) {
    val todos by todoViewModel.todos.collectAsState()
    var inputText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight().padding(8.dp)) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(8.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
        ) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                value = inputText,
                onValueChange = { inputText = it }
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
            Button(onClick = {
                if (inputText.isNotBlank()) {
                    todoViewModel.addTodo(inputText)
                    inputText = ""
                }
            }) {
                Text(text = "Add Todo")
            }
        }
        LazyColumn {
            items(todos) { item ->
                todoItem(item, removeTodo = { todoViewModel.removeTodo(item.id) })
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun todoItem(todo: Todo, removeTodo: () -> Unit) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(8.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
            .background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            Text(
                text = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss, dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(todo.createdAt),
                color = Color.LightGray,
                fontSize = 10.sp,
            )
            Text(
                text = todo.title,
                fontSize = 20.sp,
                color = Color.White
            )
        }
        IconButton(onClick = { removeTodo() }) {
            Icon(
                Icons.Rounded.Delete,
                tint = Color.White,
                contentDescription = "Delete"
            )
        }
    }
}

When I add a todo the state updates correctly. I only get an exception when deleting a todo.
It seems like the UI is trying to access an index that no longer exists after the item is removed.
How can I ensure the state updates correctly and avoid this exception?
I also found a 6 month old question where updating the dependencies work but it did not for me.

When you call loadTodos() you set the value of your flow to the list returned from TodoManager.getTodos(). That function always returns the same list, though: The content of the list may have changed, but the list itself is still the same.
That's a serious issue. Actually, there are two:

The flow only updates when the new value is different from the current value. Since you set the same list, the flow won't trigger its collectors and nothing happens in your UI although the content of the list has changed.
The list is a mutable list and you feed that list to your LazyColumn. That is not allowed: When the list is mutated (i.e., an element is removed) the LazyColumn is now in an undefined state and your app crashes.

Now, what you need to do is to make the list you store in the flow immutable. When the list changes, you need a new list with the updated content. Actually, TodoManager shouldn't even expose its internal mutable state, so instead of simply returning todoList you should return a copy:
fun getTodos(): List<Todo> {
    return todoList.toList()
}

toList() creates a read-only copy of the list.
That's it: Your flow now detects that this is a new value and properly informs its collectors of this new value. The LazyColum will get a new list and everything works as expected.
Remember: Make sure everything your composables get their hands on is either immutable or a MutableState, otherwise you will run into more of these problems.

Thanks for the explanation. This solution works perfectly.
